# how do i convert ASCII to HEX in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

I have a requirement where i need to convert ASCII to HEX in Jmeter 5.0
I am pretty new to this Jmeter, so can I get a clear idea on how to implement this and
how do i convert?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

JMeter comes with [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) library so you can use [Hex](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) class to convert your ASCII string into corresponding hexadecimal value using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString('your ASCII string'.getBytes('UTF-8')),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)